# Struggling with Selenium - entering username and password

Tags: python, html, selenium

This is the code I have

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://website.com")

element_user = driver.find_elements_by_id("user").send_keys("name123")
```

I keep getting this error

```
element_user = driver.find_elements_by_id("user").send_keys("")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `find_elements_by_id` notice the `s` in `elements`.

> [DOCS](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_elements_by_id) (epmhasis mine)
>
> Returns:
>
> **list of WebElement** - a list with elements if any was found. An empty list if not

There's also a method [`find_element_by_id`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_id), that returns a single element if found.

Answer (score 1):

Find element**s** returns a list. Use `find_element_by_id`

Answer (score 1):

`find_elements_*` returns a list, for a single `WebElement` use `find_element_*`. In addition, `send_keys()` doesn't have `return` statement so it returns default `None`. Split the command to two lines or remove the assignment

```
driver.find_element_by_id("user").send_keys("name123")
# or
element_user = driver.find_elements_by_id("user")
element_user.send_keys("name123")
```